# User authentication using Rails and React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to figure out how to fix my authentication using Ruby on Rails and React. I have been able to login but it automatically logs out whenever I refresh the page. What am I missing here?

My SesssionsController: Checks credentials and also logout feature included

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
       user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
       if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        render json: user, status: :created
       else
        render json: {error: {login: "invalid username or password"}}, status: :unauthorized
       end
    end

    def destroy
        session.delete :user_id
        head :no_content
    end
end
```

Login Frontend (React): This is where users enters their credentials and send it to my sessions controller to check if the credential is valid.

```
import React, {  useState } from 'react';
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import './style/login.css';

function Login({setUser}) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username:username, password:password }),
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((user) => setUser(user));
      navigate("/")
  }
  
  return (
    <div className='login_wrapper'>
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    <form className='login_form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={username}
        placeholder="Username"
        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
      /><br/>
      <input
        type="password"
        value={password}
        placeholder="Password"
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      /><br/>
      <button className="login_btn" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <div><Link to='/signup'>First time? Register Now!</Link></div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login
```

App.js: storing user data in useState

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/auth")
    .then((r) => {
      if (r.ok) {
        r.json()
        .then((user) => setUser(user));
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return(
    <>  
    <Navbar user={user} setUser={setUser} />
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home user={user}/>}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login setUser={setUser} />}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/signup" element={<Signup setUser={setUser}/>}></Route>
    </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

When I log in, it doesn't save any sessions to the browser - why is this? Here's the image:

[image: React front-end]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the local storage for storing token in your browser, later on you can use that token for maintaining your session. localStorage.setItem('token'). whenever you logout delete token from localStorage at destroy route. There are two ways for generating token, one is you can generate the token manaully using devise and the other is you can use jwt for generating token at backend.
below is user model for generating token manually

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable, and 
:omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

 before_save :ensure_authentication_token_is_present

def ensure_authentication_token_is_present
if authentication_token.blank?
  self.authentication_token = generate_authentication_token
end


   def generate_authentication_token
    loop do
     token = Devise.friendly_token
     break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My react is quite rusty, but you might find these helpful:

- https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/
- https://medium.com/@austinrhoads/session-store-with-react-rails-api-116a9efe3c30
- https://medium.com/@altanner/react-user-authentication-with-rails-sessions-and-redux-194b5d31fe5a

Googling some variation of `rails app with react not setting session cookie` will probably also get you where you need to go.

Comment: These links are undoubtedly helpful. Just a quick steer though - on Stack Overflow we have the concept of the "link only answer", which is a classification of answer that may be deleted by virtue of it only being a signpost to other place(s) on the web. Since we want answers (and indeed questions) to be self-contained here, it is ideal for them to contain their own material if possible (with links optionally given in an addendum). Thus if you can summarise the essence of those posts in your answer, that'd be a great service to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) for authentication, since it is easy to set up and also easily customizable.

If you want, you can pass `current_user` (Devise's authentication variable, which is the currently logged in user) as a prop to your React components. Alternatively, you can pass instance variables to each component, and possibly pass them conditionally depending on authentication status.

For example, if you want to show posts and comments to authenticated users, but non-authenticated users should only see the first comment on a post, you could do the following on your controller:

```
@posts = Post.all
if current_user
  @comments = Comment.all
else
  @comments = Comment.first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use proxy:

```
//vite.config.js
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
    
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
      server: {
        proxy: {
          '/api': {
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
            rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

That issue has troubled me for a month, but today was a breakthrough.

Then in the fetch component use :

```js
      const handleLogin = async () => {
        try {
          console.log(formData.email); // Log the email before sending the request
      
          const response = await axios.post('/api/login', {
            email: formData.email,
            password: formData.password
          });
          console.log(response.data);
          // Process the response data here
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          // Handle any errors here
        }
      };
```